woocommerce change/create attributes and terms based on product title
I have a custom plugin ive been working on to take product title data and create attributes/terms or assign them if they are already created. The output generates a log that shows these attributes were created and logged, however when I go into produts, none of these attributes/terms have actually been assigned.
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Skincare Attributes
 * Description: A custom plugin to assign attributes to WooCommerce skincare products based on their titles.
 * Version: 1.1.0
 * Author: willybilly
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

function skincare_categorize_products() {
    global $wpdb;

    $products = wc_get_products(array(
        'limit' => -1, // Retrieve all products
        'status' => 'publish',
    ));

    $attribute_map = array(
        'brand' => array(
            'cerave', 'la roche-posay', 'neutrogena', 'fresh', 'philosophy', 'tatcha', 'clinique', 'bioderma', 'drunk elephant', 'kiehl\'s', 'paula\'s choice', 'thayers', 'pixi', 'the ordinary', 'ren', 'mario badescu', 'murad', 'cosrx', 'skinceuticals', 'vichy', 'estee lauder', 'olay', 'sunday riley', 'l\'oreal', 'belif', 'eltamd', 'aveeno', 'shiseido', 'blue lizard', 'coola'
        ),
        'ingredient' => array(
            'hyaluronic acid', 'vitamin c', 'retinol', 'niacinamide', 'glycolic acid', 'salicylic acid', 'lactic acid', 'peptides', 'ceramides', 'antioxidants'
        ),
        'skin_type' => array(
            'oily', 'dry', 'combination', 'sensitive', 'normal'
        ),
        'concern' => array(
            'anti-aging', 'acne', 'hydration', 'brightening', 'dark spots', 'redness'
        )
    );

    $log = [];

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product_name = strtolower($product->get_name());
        $product_description = strtolower($product->get_description());

        $generation_notes = [];
        $new_attributes = [];

        try {
            // Assign attributes based on keywords
            foreach ($attribute_map as $attribute_name => $criteria) {
                foreach ($criteria as $criterion) {
                    $criterion_slug = sanitize_title($criterion);

                    if (strpos($product_name, strtolower($criterion)) !== false || strpos($product_description, strtolower($criterion)) !== false) {
                        $new_attributes[] = $criterion;
                        $attribute_slug = wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name($attribute_name);

                        if (!taxonomy_exists($attribute_slug)) {
                            register_taxonomy($attribute_slug, 'product', array('label' => ucfirst(str_replace('-', ' ', $attribute_name)), 'hierarchical' => false));
                            $generation_notes[] = "Registered new taxonomy '$attribute_slug'.";
                        }

                        if (!term_exists($criterion_slug, $attribute_slug)) {
                            $term = wp_insert_term($criterion, $attribute_slug, array('slug' => $criterion_slug));
                            if (is_wp_error($term)) {
                                $generation_notes[] = "Failed to insert term '$criterion' for taxonomy '$attribute_slug'. Error: " . $term->get_error_message();
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                $generation_notes[] = "Inserted new term '$criterion' for taxonomy '$attribute_slug'.";
                            }
                        }

                        wp_set_object_terms($product->get_id(), $criterion_slug, $attribute_slug, true);
                        $generation_notes[] = "Set attribute '$criterion' for '$attribute_name'.";
                    }
                }
            }

            // Verify attributes are assigned
            foreach ($attribute_map as $attribute_name => $criteria) {
                $attribute_slug = wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name($attribute_name);
                $assigned_attributes = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), $attribute_slug, array('fields' => 'names'));
                if (!is_wp_error($assigned_attributes) && !empty($assigned_attributes)) {
                    $generation_notes[] = "Verified attributes assigned for '$attribute_name': " . implode(', ', $assigned_attributes);
                } else {
                    $generation_notes[] = "No attributes assigned for '$attribute_name' or error retrieving attributes.";
                }
            }

            $log[] = array(
                'product_id' => $product->get_id(),
                'product_name' => $product->get_name(),
                'added_attributes' => $new_attributes,
                'generation_notes' => $generation_notes
            );

            $product->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $log[] = array(
                'product_id' => $product->get_id(),
                'product_name' => $product->get_name(),
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
    }

    // Log the results for debugging
    file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'categorization_log.txt', json_encode($log, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}

function wfh_add_admin_menu() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'tools.php',
        'Skincare Attributes',
        'Skincare Attributes',
        'manage_options',
        'skincare-attributes',
        'wfh_categorizer_page'
    );
}

function wfh_categorizer_page() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['wfh_categorize_products'])) {
        skincare_categorize_products();
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<h1>Skincare Attribution</h1>';
        echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'categorization_log.txt') . '</pre>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>Skincare Attributes</h1>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="wfh_categorize_products" value="1">
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Categorize Products" class="button button-primary">
                </p>
            </form>
            <pre id="categorization-log"></pre>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'wfh_add_admin_menu');


I tried changing it to the slugs, was expecting this to work but it didnt. Wondering if the problem is with woocommerce or other syntax, labeling.

to add, the output logs generated are showing that it has 'correctly assigned the attributions and terms and verified it' but it really has not when you look at the woocommerce attributes. Wondering if this is a database issue, a cache issue or maybe logic error??
